# Enabling directory browsing apache2 - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-server

I have used the below command in order to disable directory browsing.

```
sudo a2dismod autoindex
```

and restarted the apache2 using below

`sudo service apache2 restart`

How to enable the directory browsing now ?

Answer (score 1):

Re-enable it with `a2enmod` :

```
sudo a2enmod autoindex
```

Comment: you can accept the answer if you are satisfied with that